# redirect the stdout and stderr into a file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, io-redirection

I want to **redirect** the output of a **system call** into a **file**.. I tried this..

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        system("ls >> temp.txt");
        return 0;
}
```

But this is only working for **system calls**.. If i put some other thing in place of `ls`, the error output is not redirected into the file.. it is just printed on the `console`..

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
system("hello >> temp.txt");
return 0;
}
```

I want the error output redirected to the file.. how can i do this? thanks..

Comment: `command 2>&1 >> temp.txt`

Comment: You need to redirect the standard error too. The exact way depends on your shell (probably bash) - look up standard error redirection.

Comment: "I want to redirect the output of a system call into a file.. I tried this..But this is only working for system calls.. " *So, what is the problem, exactly? Sounds like mission accomplished.*

Comment: Note that calling `system` and system calls are different things, and `ls` is neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it can be achieved by

```
system("hello > temp.txt 2>&1");
```

This will direct both standard output and standard error to the file temp.txt..

while

```
system("hello 2>&1 > temp.txt");
```

This will only direct standard output to temp.txt..

**NOTE:**

The greater-than sign should not be separated by spaces from the number of the file descriptor. If it would be separated, we would be pointing the output to a file again.